# Is it possible to use ng-boostrap with a custom bootstrap css that uses a prefix?

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on an Angular project in which we have to use a custom bootstrap where most of the classes have been prefixed, for example `form-control` becomes `prefix-form-control`, sadly that's not a decision I can fight against.

Since it's an Angular project that uses features such as dropdowns, modals, selects etc...I wanted to use ng-bootstrap https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap but I can't find anywhere (neither by googling nor looking on the github repo/official website) something that lets me use such a customized bootstrap version. Was I not thorough enough in my research, is this something impossible to do or there is an alternative way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option in ngBootstrap to do so. Options you have:

- fork ngb and maintaining this fork
- create a feature request in nbg to make this possible ( maybe you can submit a PR for this? )